# OSX Automatically create PDF from template when email arrives

Tags: macos, pdf, automation, apple-mail

Is it possible (and if so through which approach) to automatically create a PDF based on a template by using input received through the Mail program?

Basically something along these lines:

1) Filter incoming email

2) if filter matches extract information from email (through REGEX)

3) create PDF based on template with previously extracted information

4) attach created PDF to email and send as reply to initial email

Is this somehow possible?

Thank you for your advice!
Tom

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you should say us what have you done till now... [Edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/995428/edit) with those information before many people start to say you _"this is not a scrip service"_. Do your attempts and when you cannot solve a problem come with the specific problem.

Comment: @Hastur: I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me, but for some advice which the correct tools are to approach this problem. I have never done anything like it before and just need to know wether it is possible at all and if so through which means. Thx Tom

Comment: Still no news... Ok, long long ago there was Majordomo to manage the mailing list... nowadays you started well dividing in steps your problem. Give a look to some [Mail retrieval agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_retrieval_agent), maybe [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/). Filtered the mails you can do a script on those. `grep` `awk` and `sed 's/placeholder/dataextracted/g'` will be your friends. Then maybe you can put the information extracted in a latex template and  _compile_ in a pdf file. Then finally you can send as attachment... or you can find a program just done.